# Powermanagement of Nexus 4 with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-touch, battery, nexus-4

I am using Ubuntu 14.10(r15) from the ubuntu-rtm/14.09/mako chanel on my Nexus 4. It runs quite good, but one big problem is still the powermanagement. The battery does not last very long. Even without using the phone it is emtpy after several hours. I can't use the alarm, because in the morning the accu is empty. Besides, the phone is often very warm; I guess, this consumes quite some energy.
Is there any solution? Is this problem known?

Answer (score 0):

Power management in Ubuntu is far from being perfect, but a battery life of a few hours only and a warm but idle phone are sure not normal. Open Terminal and enter `top`. It shows a list of processes sorted by CPU usage. You probably have to put the phone to landscape orientation to see full process names. An idle phone should have no processes taking more than 10% CPU time. If you see any process taking significantly more CPU time, check for bugs at https://launchpad.net or file a new one.

Unfortunately, it's quite difficult to find the right project belonging to the process in question. If in doubt, ask the [mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-phone) for assistance.